# What problems will an intelligent species on a low gravity planet face advancing to space exploration?

Tags: gravity, technological-development

From the information that I have found, low gravity planets will be able to produce taller/larger flora and fauna that will be lighter and more spindly in structure with flying, gliding and leaping being predominant forms of locomotion but I was wondering what if any difficulties they will have advancing towards building rockets for space exploration.

The planet I am designing will have around 60% earths gravity and will have the same atmosphere density and composition of gasses, so flight and launching into space will involve less energy than on earth but will they be able to develop all the necessary technology for rockets? or will any of the processes for gathering and manufacturing be made difficult or impossible because of the low gravity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I thought I would save asking lots of questions by putting it in one question, would changing it to problems of advancing on just a low gravity planet be ok?

Comment: We have a strict one question per post rule. You will want to make sure toe [edit] your post to ask a single question. In addition to only asking about one type of planet, you're currently asking about literally every technological development from paleolithic rocks-as-tools to re-usable rockets, deep learning and genetic engineering. You'll want to narrow down the scope of the technologies you're asking about as well.

Comment: I guess on such a planet, the atmosphere reaches higher up. Not sure how that affects space travel – you low orbit might need to be higher.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after? All other things being equal, reaching space from a low-gravity planet should be greatly easier than from Earth… but what other things matter for you?

Answer (score 6):

#### Acceleration

For the most part, making a rocket that can reach space is exponentially easier the less gravity you have.  At 0.6G you will still have no problem building gravity assisted machines.  Basically anything that they make out of steel will behave the same way in their gravity as things we make out of aluminum. Any rare case where things become too light, you can just add some extra mass to get to the desired weight.  So if you have a 30-ton pile driver that only weighs 18 tons on this other world that is having a hard time staying stable, just at a 12 ton concrete weight to it, and you are fine.

So, building an infrastructure and manufacturing a rocket will be easy, the biggest challenge for a light worlder will be surviving the G forces of a rocket launch.  Evolution will only design a body to resist so far above normal forces before more toughness stops making you more selectively fit.  In general, a mid-sized mammal can only sustain about 3Gs of acceleration, and up to 9Gs, but only for very short amounts of time.  If you assume your intelligent species followed a similar evolutionary path to humans, then they will also follow this 3-9G tolerance, only for them, G=5.9m/s, not 9.8m/s.

This means they will need to design their rockets to accelerate slower which in turn means that the rocket will be under the effect of their planet's gravity for longer (relative to the size of the planet) reducing their possible fuel economy.

So, yes, this alien species could get off of their home world more easily than we can get off of ours, but if they were to be brought to Earth, the required slower accelerations would likely mean that they could not use chemical rockets to get off of an Earth like world at all.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a smaller planet is significantly easier to launch from. However, that's not quite the same as saying a lower-surface-gravity planet is necessarily easier to launch from.

The first thing simplifying launch, as you mention, is surface gravity. During a launch, a significant amount of energy is spent on "gravity loss" -- simplified, the portion of the launch energy that is countering the force of gravity instead of adding kinetic energy to the vehicle.

The second thing that's (probably) making launch much simpler is the reduced escape velocity of the smaller planet. This is (approximately) the total amount of kinetic energy that needs to be added to the launch vehicle to achieve orbit. A low-gravity planet that is similar to Earth in composition is a small planet, and will have a lower escape velocity -- easier launches. But it is possible to have a planet with a lower surface gravity and a higher escape velocity. This would be a more massive planet (deeper gravity well), where the surface of the planet is disproportionately far from the center (so that the surface gravity is measured higher in the gravity well). This can be the case in a low density planet, for example. So there are knobs you can tweak here to have low surface gravity and challenging launches.

There's a final component of launch difficulty which works against a smaller planet, although it's likely smaller in magnitude. Besides paying the energy cost of accelerating to escape velocity, plus the gravity losses during the time of acceleration, you also need to pay the energy cost of atmospheric drag. And a planet with lower surface gravity will have a higher "scale height" for the atmosphere. Intuitively, if you have the same atmospheric composition, temperature, and pressure on the surface, but less gravity holding it there and generating that pressure, you must have more total atmosphere. In practice a planet with 0.6 g surface gravity will have a scale height of ~1.67x the Earth's scale height; so a launch will spend more time in denser atmosphere. This gives a launcher two options -- accelerate at roughly the same speed as an earth launch and deal with the energy cost of higher drag and deal with the much higher structural loads at max Q; or, accelerate more slowly to keep max Q about the same (targeting transonic at around 1.3x the scale height), but give up the gains from gravity loss, since more time will be spent fighting the reduced gravity.

Finally, it's worth asking whether an Earth-style launch is optimal on a reduced-gravity planet. It's certainly possible, and probably (depending on planet density) easier; but are there other things that become disproportionately even easier? This is again where atmospheric scale height plays a part. On Earth, air launch of rockets to orbit is investigated regularly; it has obvious appeal in that it allows a significant reduction in atmospheric drag as experienced by the launch vehicle, and has some operational benefits, but is quite complex, especially for larger payloads. On a lower-gravity planet, more of the launch losses are atmospheric drag and less is gravity loss, so an air launch makes more sense. In addition, the thicker atmosphere higher may make the aerospace engineers on your planet more comfortable with high-altitude aerodynamic flight; while on Earth aerodynamic flight above 20 km or so is rare, this would be equivalent to well over 30 km on your planet.